# Battery wiring for DIY speaker question

Tags: batteries, amplifier, speakers

could anyone tell me if i can wire the 12V battery to get around 20V out of the whole set? Right now it's wired in parallel which increases capacity but i need around 20V for the amplifier to have enough power (it can work on 12 but at 50% of volume). If i were to wire the battery in series to the charger's + or - that would fry it, right?

---

[image: Battery circuit]

[image: Entire circuit]

Comment: 1) Your regulation circuits are not defined, and a schematic or datasheet would help. 2) You seem to have batteries of different voltages and chemistry in parallel. Not sure that is a good or safe idea.

Answer (score 0):

Chargers normally supply current pulses and thus would cause severe noise ripple in series with a battery and perhaps create havoc if the amp has some boost regulator.

What is the max voltage rating on  the ojačevalnik (amp.)

Normally 12~14.2V is supplied to auto audio units with the Amp using a step-up voltage converter with a differential output drive to get max power at the lowest voltage.

Comment: amp support 12 - 24V, also the battery part will have 3 batteries in series to form 12V ish

Comment: The problem is the charger pulse noise added to the stable voltage Li-Ion batteries so you cannot get clean 20V